# not able to install any package using Yum always says package not found

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I'm installing "FASTX Toolkit" using yum but not able to install .My operating system is RHEL v7 with 64 bit

please give me some suggestion how to solve this

Comment: Copy the exact command you are trying and its output as well as your repo files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve